# creating form in controller cakephp

Tags: forms, cakephp

I am trying to use Form helper in Controller. I need it because I need to store the form HTML in another file. My code in controller is as follows:

```
<?php
function html_form($id){
$form_fields=array();//has many values
$html .= $this->Form->create('web_forms', array(
            'action' => 'html_form
        ));
$html .= $this->Form->input($form_fields['name']);
return $html;
?>
```

When I called this function, it throws an error as follows.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in ****`

How to use Form helper in controller??

Comment: you have too mich space between $this and Form

Comment: Please read http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html - also, forms are not built in the controller but the view.

Comment: @mark I knew very well that forms are built only in Views. But now, I am in neccessity to create dynamic forms and so I need the above function to return the form. That's the reason I have been trying to build forms in controller. I need to use Form helper in controller. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you are actually trying to do. _Where_ exactly, and _why_ exactly do you want to do _what_ exactly with the form HTML?

Answer (score 1):

try to change this:

```
$html .= $form->create('web_forms', array(
            'action' => 'html_form'
        ));
```

to this:

```
$html .= $this->Form->create('web_forms', array(
            'action' => 'html_form'
        ));
```

Comment: Earlier I used $this -> Form -> create(). It also showed the same error. That's why I tried to change it. Both are not working. I would like to know the syntax used in controllers.

Comment: Thenm try to put into your question more information, like name of the file, or other information because this code works fine @Ganesh

Comment: Are you pretty much sure that $this -> Form -> create() works directly in controller. Because I tried ways like $form-> create(). But it is showing error like calling function on a non-object. Can you explain the meaning of this error?

Comment: $this->Form is a helper class, which only works on the presentation layer (Views), which is what the error is basically indicating. To create dynamic forms, which is what you're apparently trying to do, you should use JavaScript, but we can't help you with so little information.

As somebody told you before, forms should be handled by views.